# How to show a portion of canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

My canvas has a background image. That image has different part such as level-1,level-2 etc. I will create few buttons. When button-1 is clicked only show level-1 portion of background image and hide other levels. Similarly for button-2 is clicked only show level-2. For example the background could look like this image:

[image]

Comment: what have you tried so far? can you provide a jsfiddle? can you show us your current code?

Comment: Yes, I tried but I think that is not a good process(draw a shap with same color of background to hide it). Other code very much similar to the link

Comment: What did you try that was not a good process? Show us something concrete. Don't expect a fully-working solution just like that.

Comment: You can treat your backgroundimage.png as a spritesheet and use the clipping version of context.drawImage to draw only your desired level on the canvas: ctx.drawImage(backgroundImage, 235, 0, 135, 280, 0, 0, 135, 280);